# Userform commandbutton to copy based on CheckBox True/False

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox, userform

Hi I am new to Excel VBA and I am stuck at below problem,

My workbook has sheet1 = Chandler_Endorsements (contains button to launch UserForm1). My Userform has 26 CheckBox and 2 CommandButton (Copy and Reset).

Each CheckBox is associated with a cell in sheet2 in the workbook. Each of the subsequent cells has a value eg. ABc, XYz, etc in a specific format.

My goal is to have the user check the CheckBox for each of the items they want to select, then select "Copy" (CommandButton1) and then they can paste those on word file. 
Eg. If they have checked checkbox1 & 2, cell associated with these checkboxes get selected and copied and later they paste on a word file.

Also if a checkbox is later unselected by user in between that cell should get selected and copied.

I have used below codes to give value to each checkbox:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
CheckBox1.Caption = Range("A3").Value
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox10_Click()
CheckBox10.Caption = Range("A14").Value
End Sub
```

And, for coping the relevant cell I am using below codes:

```
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Else: CheckBox1.Value = False
  End If

  If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("A4").Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Else: CheckBox2.Value = False
  End If
```

But by using above codes it is not coping the every cells which I have selected (checked in checkbox). Kindly help me with the correct codes.

Comment: Is there a numerical order in the cells that corresponds with the checkbox? (Like `CheckBox1 = Cell A3`, `CheckBox2 = Cell A4`?

Comment: Yes. I have set my sheet1 in numerical order and then used below codes:                                                                                                      If UserForm1.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    SelectRange = SelectRange + "," + "A3"
End If                                                                                                     'So AS, checkbox2,3,4,5.......

Answer (score 1):

here is a suggestion to do it a different way:

- This code steps through each `Control` in the `UserForm`
- checks if its a `CheckBox`
- validates if its `.Value = True`
- It stores the data into the `String`
- Sets `CheckBox.Value` to `False`
- Transfer the `String` data to the Clipboard

`Option Explicit`

```
Sub TestRun()
Dim cCont As Control
Dim StrCopy As String
Dim IntI As Long
Dim Mydata As New DataObject

IntI = 1

For Each cCont In UserForm1.Controls

If TypeName(cCont) = "CheckBox" Then
    If cCont.Value = True Then
        StrCopy = StrCopy & Chr(10) & ActiveSheet.Range("B" & IntI).Value
        cCont.Value = False
    End If
IntI = IntI + 1
End If
Next cCont

Mydata.SetText StrCopy
Mydata.PutInClipboard
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This...You can apply auto open instead of clicking CommandButton in sheet 1.

Check and record the checkBoxes which user select and copy the cells at the same time. And then, user can paste to word file manually.

```
Sub auto_open()
UserForm1.Show
Call Copy
End Sub


Sub Copy()
Dim SelectRange as String
SelectRange = ""

If UserForm1.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    SelectRange = SelectRange + "," + "A3"
End If
If UserForm1.CheckBox2.Value = True Then
    SelectRange = SelectRange + "," + "A4"
End If
'So AS, checkbox3,4,5.......

If SelectRange <> "" Then
    SelectRange = Mid(SelectRange, 2, Len(SelectRange))
    Sheets("sheet2").Range(SelectRange).Select
    Selection.copy
End If

UserForm1.CheckBox1.Value = False
UserForm1.CheckBox2.Value = False
'So AS, checkbox3,4,5.......

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now the userform is opening automatically by using above code. As I have linked all the 26 checkbox with 26 different rows in sheet1.  But there is slight issue in the other part.

Comment: For example If I have checked checkbox 1,2, 15 & 25 which is linked to row no 1,2,15 & 25 respectively in sheet1  and then click on the commandbutton (Copy), it is selecting only the selected rows which is correct but when I trying to paste this on the word file, all the rows from 1 to 25 is getting pasted where I wanted to paste only row no 1,2,15 & 25. 
Kindly help me to resolve this issue. 
I have another commandbutton named ‘Reset’ and I want to give a code to it that when I click on this all checked checkbox should be unchecked and my sheet should be refreshed means no selection or copy.

Comment: There is a stupid method but it work. 1. You can transfer rows value or copy rows to sheet 3, and then copy / paste to word file. 2. You can apply this code "UserForm1.CheckBox1.Value = False" to your reset CommandButton.  If it work for you, please accept this answer with green mark.

Comment: Yes. That could also be done. But now I am using below codes and it works perfect for me.                                                                              If UserForm1.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    st = st & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
End If

If UserForm1.CheckBox2.Value = True Then
    st = st & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
End If
'So as, checkbox3,4,5.....

Comment: And then I using                                                                                       Dim Mydata As New DataObject
Mydata.SetText st
Mydata.PutInClipboard

Comment: Then try this.... UserForm1.CheckBox1.Value = True Then st = st & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & CheckBox1.Caption End If If UserForm1.CheckBox2.Value = True Then st = st & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & CheckBox2.Caption End If 'So as, checkbox3,4,5.....I hope this will work.